# How to determine the equation of the curve that represents the solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The curve shown below represents the solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+1, x > 0$

[image]

Use $y=wx$ (where $w$ is a function of $x$) to determine the equation of the curve in simplest form.

Why is $w$ there? What does it mean? I have no idea how to start, I tried put it in to online calculator and it says that I need to find the integrating factor, which I don't think I have learnt it yet. So how do you do this question?

Answer (score 1):

$w’ x + w = w + 1 \implies w’ = {1 \over x} \implies w = \ln\left(x\right) + \mbox{a constant} \implies y = x\ln\left(x\right) - 2x$.

[Graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%20Log%5Bx%5D-2%20x%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C10%7D%5D).

Comment: Thank you Mr Marin, can I ask you what is this "technique" called?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk I guess there isn’t any name around it $yet$ !!!.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+1$$
$$xdy=(y+x)dx$$
$$\dfrac {xdy-ydx}{x^2}=\dfrac {dx}x$$
Integration gives:
$$\dfrac y x=\ln x +C$$
$$\implies y(x)=x(\ln x +C)$$
With initial condition;
$$y(e^2)=0$$
$$ 0=e^2(2+C$$
$$\implies C= -2$$
So that:
$$ y(x)=x(\ln x -2)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just couldn't see it? How did you know I have to use the quotient rule?

Answer (score 0):

Recognize the differential from Quotient rule and integrate

$$\dfrac {xdy-ydx}{x^2}=\dfrac {dx}x\implies \dfrac{y}{x}=(\ln x + c)$$

It does not help to evaluate  the constant $c$ at $ (x=0,y=0)$ because of the infinities.

The given point on x-axis is $ (e^2,0).$ It is suitable, and when plugged in gives
$$c=-2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just couldn't see it? How did you know I have to use the quotient rule?

Comment: Associate every differential coefficient with its corresponding *differential form * during derivative learning itself, for its  form recognition. For example $ d(xy)= x\; dy+ y\; dx ,\quad  d(u/v)=(v \;du-u \;dv)/v^2; $ An easy way to do this is to bring in $t$ , differentiate w.r.t.$t\;$ and cut off all the $dt$'s occurring in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what is a differential coefficient?

Comment: The derivative has also another name, the differential coefficient$\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: If you liked an answer consider accepting it.

Comment: I definitely would sir, but I just couldn't wrap my head around this. I fail to see how to introduce quotient rule into this. I apologise, does this "technique" has a name?

Comment: As told it is a *differential form*. If the area of a rectangular sheet is $A$, then the frame around it has differential  area $ x dy+y dx$